# Power Steering Fluid Leaking from some kind of ECU controlled actuator

Tags: nissan, power-steering, leak

I've got a 99 Nissan Almera 1.6L MTX ( European version of the Sentra ) and I've noticed that occasionally power steering fluid ( ATF ) will leak / squirt out from this thing:

[image]

First of all, I'm not even sure what this thing is and what function it serves in the power steering system.  I couldn't locate it in the 95 workshop manual.

I circled the source of the leak.  Any idea's appreciated.

**EDIT 13/6/2017**

OK, so after Paulster's comment I was able to locate this thing in the manual:

[image]

So, the question is how to fix it.

Comment: This will most likely be the pressure side hose. The sensor, I believe, measures the power steering fluid pressure. If it drops too low it will register on the dash. At least that's what I believe is going on. More than likely the leak is coming from where the hose is coupled to the fitting. There's a pressure fitting located under the holder. If you take the one bolt off (you can see the tip sticking through the holder), the hose should come free and you can see it better. Most likely you'll need to replace the pressure hose to fix the issue. A hydraulic shop may be able to fix it for you.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Thanks to your comment I was able to locate the item and it is some kind of PS pressure switch assembly.  Want to convert your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will most likely be the pressure side hose. The sensor, I believe, measures the power steering fluid pressure. If it drops too low it will register on the dash. At least that's what I believe is going on. More than likely the leak is coming from where the hose is coupled to the fitting. There's a pressure fitting located under the holder. If you take the one bolt off (you can see the tip sticking through the holder), the hose should come free and you can see it better. Most likely you'll need to replace the pressure hose to fix the issue. A hydraulic shop may be able to fix it for you.

Comment: You think a hydraulic shop could just put a new fitting on the existing hose, or would they need to make up a whole new hose?